# LWJGL 3.0.0 glMapBuffer

Tags: opengl, java, lwjgl, lwjgl3

I am currently working on a project and usually in C++ I use the function.
`ByteBuffer glMapBuffer(int target, int access)`

usage:

```
FloatBuffer buffer = glMapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY).order(
    ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
```

But in java (lwjgl 3.0.0) this function returns null, because of this reason it throws a NullPointerException.

Anyone any idea how to use this function in java?

There are several functions:

```
glMapBuffer(int target, int access)  
glMapBuffer(int target, int access, ByteBuffer old_buffer)  
glMapBuffer(int target, int access, long length, ByteBuffer old_buffer)
```

I hope this is specific enough, thank you for your help :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited Answer**

Before writing to a Buffer Object, you must have some space allocated in GPU's memory, you can grow or shrink the Buffer Objects via:

```java
glBufferData(int target, long size, int usage);
```

When the Buffer Object already have `size` bytes, you can call `glMapBuffer` passing the full size, or some smaller number (you dont have to actually shrink the Buffer Object if it will most likely grow again soon)

```java
glMapBuffer(int target, int access)
```

Returns a brand new ByteBuffer, with the current size of Buffer Object;

```java
glMapBuffer(int target, int access, ByteBuffer old_buffer)
```

Returns a new ByteBuffer, or reuses the old object (if not null), with the current size of Buffer Object (not the old_buffer object);

```java
glMapBuffer(int target, int access, long length, ByteBuffer old_buffer)
```

This is like the previous one, but it is faster because it don't have to query for the Buffer Object's size.

When passing an old_buffer, it unmaps it first (and may use some optimization) before mapping it again.

Don't forget to call `glUnmapBuffer(int target)` at the end of it all. (After that your mapped ByteBuffer will be in an invalid state and you must not read/write to it)

**Example**

```java
private int id;
private long currentSize;

public void updateBuffer(...) {

    long calculatedSize = ...;
    if (currentSize < calculatedSize) {
        currentSize = calculatedSize;
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, currentSize, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    }
    ByteBuffer bb = glMapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY);
    try {
        FloatBuffer floatBuffer = ...
        ...
    } finally {
        glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have an initialization method where the buffer gets bound I specify a pre-calculated size.
I'm trying to draw the triangles dynamic.
After playing around with it, plus using your tip, it still throws a NullPointerException :(   

Anyways thank you for your help!

Comment: You don't have to pre allocate the buffer (actually you can't), what this method does is (more or less) map a previously allocated GPU memory block so you can access via a ByteBuffer. When you create a (direct) ByteBuffer you are allocating space in the CPU's memory. Store your pre-calculated size only, and a ByteBuffer pointer (`private ByteBuffer mappedBuffer = null;`) then use mappedBuffer = `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY, preCalcSize, mappedBuffer);` after that you can `FloatBuffer buf = ....`. Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry, I forget something, you must call

`glBufferData(int target​, long size​, int usage​);`

to pre-allocate the memory in GPU before, at initialization, or when the required size grows.

Comment: I did the initialization (glBufferData) but I think there might be just an error in the native code because now it doesn't even allow me to do the same thing I used about 2 hours ago.. I think the native code might have been corrupted